# RASA - API calling in local mode and server

Tags: python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-x

I am creating a chat bot using RASA X

i installed Rasa in my local system and a server system

Local mode :
In local mode i used

http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook

and data as
{
"sender": "Rasa",
"message": "hi"
}

and got the corresponign response

### Server

installed rasa using [Rasa Server Install](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/install/quick-install-script/) this link
and trained and then i tried to acces the api  used for the local mode

http://serverIp/webhooks/rest/webhook

but is showing error

```
Error: Requested URL /webhooks/rest/webhook not found
```

Why this is showing

How can i access it through API ??

i am using python 3.6.8

Answer (score 0):

"***/webhooks/rest/webhook***" this is not URL , it's an HTTP Post Method , you can't access it from Browser.

If you are trying to open your rasa on web browser  run :

***rasa x***

It will generate a link for Rasa UI , which you can access from browser